# Vue - child component prop doesn't update after change on parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have component let's say "middle" with prop "element" from let's day "top" component - it's object and I use references to populate and update some data. This object has properties "id" and "cost". On middle component, I have select with v-model to element.id.

If user change selection, I checked some data in middle component method and set new cost. And it works fine - if I just use {{ element.cost }} to display data, everything is fine.

But I also sends this element.cost to let's say "deep" component - I use it to render custom input field and this cost is populated as value. This component use internal data to store and update model because I also use Cleave.

```
beforeMount () {
  // model is from middle (parent)
  this.value = this.model
}
```

and watch changes:

```
watch: {
            value: function (newValue) {
                // here some validation
                this.$emit('input', this.value)
            }
}
```

And it works fine - if I modify input, middle element also has this changes.

The problem is when I modify element.cost on "middle" level - after change in selection. Even if I use $this.set, even if I use this.$forceUpdate, input on "deep" is not updated. I tried to add watcher inside deep t monitor model, but it doesn't see any changes from parent. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a working codepen/jsFiddle demo? it would be great help to find out the problem.

Comment: sounds like you are changing the prop content in the _"middle"_ level component. The design of these reactive frameworks expects data changes flow in one direction. That means the changes to the data have to be done at the data-owning level. Any change to the data will update the props. Props' data/value are not watched by the parent for changes.

Comment: @Daniel yes and I know this. And yes, I make changes on "middle", but want to see changes no on "top", but on "deep" - on child of middle. And it doesn't work.

Comment: @LukaszTkacz It looks like you're watching `value` in your "deep" component.  You would need to watch `model`, which is the prop being passed from middle to deep, correct?  And then update `value`.  This should be doable by making `value` a computed property which returns `this.model`.